# How to do 'git clone --depth 1 --sparse --no-checkout --filter=blob:none' in libgit2

Tags: git, libgit2

For context I want to git sparse-checkout just one file using these commands inside libgit2:

```
git clone --depth 1 --sparse --no-checkout --filter=blob:none https://github.com/libgit2
cd libgit2
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "package.json" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout
```

There is [open pr for libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/6396) that adds `--depth` support.

But what about other options for clone. Can I do: `--sparse`, `--no-checkout` and `--filter=blob:none'`?

Also how would `git config core.sparseCheckout true` and sparse-checkout of just one file/folder work?

Is it possible to do with libgit2?

After above commands for example, only `package.json` file was fetched and checked out from the repo. Nothing else.

I would love to do the same using libgit2. Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution yet? I'd like to do the same